# How to enable QT_DEBUG_DRAW?

Tags: c++, qt

I am currently coding a qt application using QT creator on windows 7.

I browse the source of Qt and saw some debug message with require QT_DEBUG_DRAW to be defined. I tried CONFIG += QT_DEBUG_DRAW, DEFINES += QT_DEBUG_DRAW in the .pro file, I tried to #define QT_DEBUG_DRAW before all the includes of QT file and I also tried to set an environnement variable QT_DEBUG_DRAW to 1, but i still don't get the prints message.

Does anybody know how to enable this prints?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, so I'm not making it an answer, but I'd say with 99% certainty that you'll have to `#define` it and recompile Qt from sources.

Comment: @SergeyTachenov sure that's what should be done. I'm taking the risk to answer it ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the pre-processing variable in your code does not change the fact that Qt was built without this variable set.

You need to recompile Qt with this pre-processing variable set. To do so, download Qt opensource and specify the variable upon configuration:

```
configure -D QT_DEBUG_DRAW
nmake
```

Comment: In the doc (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/debug.html), it's written we can debug plugins, i wondered if it could be easily activated for drawing too.
Thank you for the answer.

Comment: @Krapow, for plugins it mentions environment variables which are obviously different from compile-time constants. If you see an `#ifdef` somewhere and you know it wasn't defined when that code was built, then this line is simply isn't compiled. So yeah, looks like you have to rebuild the whole thing.